# Defining Spells Based on Multiple Criterion W/Missing Data

Tags: r, traminer

I'm trying something that I thought would be rather simple in R, but is giving me more trouble then I bargained for.  I'd like to use R to define spells based on multiple criteria, while ignoring missing data.  The goal is then to compute wage means across spells using the `aggregate` command.  I suspect that the tools provided in the `TraMineR` package may be used to accomplish this, but I'm having a hard time figuring out how.

For example, given the following data:

```
Caseid     Year        Unemployed  EmployerID  occID   indID  Wage           
1          1999         0          1           1       1      5.00       
1          2000         NA         NA          NA      NA     NA       
1          2001         NA         NA          NA      NA     NA       
1          2002         0          1           1       2      6.00       
2          1999         0          1           1       1      4.00
2          2000         0          1           1       1      5.00
2          2001         0          1           1       1      6.00
2          2002         1          1           1       1      6.00
3          1999         0          1           1       1      4.00
3          2000         0          3           1       1      5.00
3          2001         0          1           4       1      5.00
3          2002         NA         NA          NA      NA     NA
4          1999         0          1           1       1      5.00
4          2000         0          1           1       1      5.00
4          2001         0          1           1       1      7.00
4          2002         0          1           1       1      7.00
```

I'd like to write code that defines spells based on changes in either employment status, employer, occupation, or industry.  In addition I'd like to ignore missing values.  Given that, the correct code should return the following vector for "Spell":

```
Caseid     Year        Unemployed  EmployerID  occID   indID  Wage   Spell         
1          1999         0          1           1       1      5.00   1     
1          2000         NA         NA          NA      NA     NA     1  
1          2001         NA         NA          NA      NA     NA     1  
1          2002         0          1           1       2      6.00   2    
2          1999         0          1           1       1      4.00   1
2          2000         0          1           1       1      5.00   1
2          2001         0          1           1       1      6.00   1
2          2002         1          1           1       1      6.00   2
3          1999         0          1           1       1      4.00   1
3          2000         0          3           1       1      5.00   2
3          2001         0          1           4       1      5.00   3
3          2002         NA         NA          NA      NA     NA     3
4          1999         0          1           1       1      5.00   1
4          2000         0          1           1       1      5.00   1
4          2001         0          1           1       1      7.00   1
4          2002         0          1           1       1      7.00   1
```

Ultimately I'd like to use the spell vector to average wages across within person spells.  Returning the following:

```
Caseid     Year        Unemployed  EmployerID  occID   indID  Wage   Spell  avgWage         
1          1999         0          1           1       1      5.00   1      5.00
1          2000         NA         NA          NA      NA     NA     1      5.00
1          2001         NA         NA          NA      NA     NA     1      5.00
1          2002         0          1           1       2      6.00   2      6.00
2          1999         0          1           1       1      4.00   1      5.00
2          2000         0          1           1       1      5.00   1      5.00
2          2001         0          1           1       1      6.00   1      5.00
2          2002         1          1           1       1      6.00   2      6.00
3          1999         0          1           1       1      4.00   1      4.00
3          2000         0          3           1       1      5.00   2      5.00
3          2001         0          1           4       1      5.00   3      5.00
3          2002         NA         NA          NA      NA     NA     3      5.00
4          1999         0          1           1       1      5.00   1      6.00
4          2000         0          1           1       1      5.00   1      6.00
4          2001         0          1           1       1      7.00   1      6.00
4          2002         0          1           1       1      7.00   1      6.00
```

Here is the data for Debugging.  One note is that the newemp (newemployer) variable is different then the example I provided it should only start a new spell if the value is 1.  So a series of 4 years where newemp=1 should not represent one spell but four different spells:

```
    df <- as.data.frame(structure(list(caseid = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), year = c(1979L, 
    1980L, 1981L, 1982L, 1983L, 1984L, 1985L, 1986L, 1987L, 1988L, 
    1989L, 1990L, 1991L, 1992L, 1993L, 1994L, 1996L, 1998L, 2000L, 
    2002L, 2004L, 2006L, 2008L, 2010L, 1979L, 1980L, 1981L, 1982L, 
    1983L, 1984L, 1985L, 1986L, 1987L, 1988L, 1989L, 1990L, 1991L, 
    1992L, 1993L, 1994L, 1996L, 1998L, 2000L, 2002L, 2004L, 2006L, 
    2008L, 2010L, 1979L, 1980L, 1981L, 1982L, 1983L, 1984L, 1985L, 
    1986L, 1987L, 1988L, 1989L, 1990L, 1991L, 1992L, 1993L, 1994L, 
    1996L, 1998L, 2000L, 2002L, 2004L, 2006L, 2008L, 2010L, 1979L, 
    1980L, 1981L, 1982L, 1983L, 1984L, 1985L, 1986L, 1987L, 1988L, 
    1989L, 1990L, 1991L, 1992L, 1993L, 1994L, 1996L, 1998L, 2000L, 
    2002L, 2004L, 2006L, 2008L, 2010L, 1979L, 1980L, 1981L, 1982L, 
    1983L, 1984L, 1985L, 1986L, 1987L, 1988L, 1989L, 1990L, 1991L, 
    1992L, 1993L, 1994L, 1996L, 1998L, 2000L, 2002L, 2004L, 2006L, 
    2008L, 2010L), unemp = c(0, NA, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, NA, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
    0, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, NA, 0, 
    0, NA, 1, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, NA, 0, 
    NA, 0, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
newemp = c(NA, NA, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, 
1, 1, 1, NA, 1, NA, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
1, NA, NA, 0, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 1, 0, 0, 1, NA, 0, 0, NA, 1, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, NA, 1, NA, 1, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), stocc = c(335, NA, 337, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 337, 337, 337, 337, 337, 23, 386, 
23, 23, 337, 389, 23, 337, 23, 337, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 276, 
276, 276, NA, 383, 376, NA, 383, NA, NA, 383, NA, 447, 468, 
155, 468, 373, 188, 243, NA, NA, 243, 22, 277, NA, 22, 469, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 274, NA, NA, NA, 313, 313, 313, 313, 313, 
NA, 313, 313, NA, 313, 178, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 329, 
329, 329, 355, 223, 223, NA, 178, NA, 178, 178, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), stind = c(711, NA, 
711, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 172, 172, 172, 172, 172, 
172, 172, 172, 172, 172, 172, 172, 172, 172, 172, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 641, 641, 641, NA, 700, 700, NA, 700, NA, NA, 
700, NA, 840, 770, 842, 862, 172, 623, 682, NA, NA, 682, 
172, 671, NA, 791, 791, NA, NA, NA, NA, 591, NA, NA, NA, 
841, 841, 841, 841, 841, NA, 712, 841, NA, 841, 841, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 850, 850, 850, 932, 850, 841, NA, 841, 
NA, 841, 841, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA), lwage = c(2.14335489273071, NA, 2.0160756111145, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2.30358457565308, 2.34806489944458, 
2.36942100524902, 2.41516351699829, 2.38407301902771, 2.23588967323303, 
2.60783195495605, 2.58224511146545, 2.68043231964111, 2.70430994033813, 
2.76339650154114, 2.76763892173767, 2.72537922859192, 2.83617949485779, 
2.88961029052734, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2.28949975967407, 2.15297079086304, 
NA, NA, 2.25023865699768, 2.20731782913208, NA, 2.15908432006836, 
NA, NA, 2.17475175857544, NA, 0.0605304837226868, 0.940007209777832, 
2.2104697227478, 2.22159194946289, 0.130852773785591, 0.725372314453125, 
2.02960777282715, NA, NA, 2.09433007240295, 2.38683438301086, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1.89671993255615, NA, NA, 
NA, 2.63665437698364, 2.7040421962738, 2.79728126525879, 
2.72129535675049, 3.03042364120483, NA, 3.02664947509766, 
2.7957558631897, NA, 2.86539578437805, 2.20382499694824, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2.08691358566284, 2.03152418136597, 
2.10608339309692, 2.17702174186707, 2.16355276107788, 3.65519332885742, 
NA, 3.80884671211243, NA, 3.37032580375671, 3.52329707145691, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA))))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Much less elegant than @BrodieG's `data.table` solution (which convinces me I really *must* familiarise myself with `data.table`!), but since I've coded it I may as well provide it here.

```
d <- read.table(text='Caseid     Year        Unemployed  EmployerID  occID   indID  Wage           
1          1999         0          1           1       1      5.00       
1          2000         NA         NA          NA      NA     NA       
1          2001         NA         NA          NA      NA     NA       
1          2002         0          1           1       2      6.00       
2          1999         0          1           1       1      4.00
2          2000         0          1           1       1      5.00
2          2001         0          1           1       1      6.00
2          2002         1          1           1       1      6.00
3          1999         0          1           1       1      4.00
3          2000         0          3           1       1      5.00
3          2001         0          1           4       1      5.00
3          2002         NA         NA          NA      NA     NA
4          1999         0          1           1       1      5.00
4          2000         0          1           1       1      5.00
4          2001         0          1           1       1      7.00
4          2002         0          1           1       1      7.00', header=TRUE)


d <- merge(unsplit(
  lapply(split(na.omit(d), na.omit(d)$Caseid), function(x) {
    cbind(x, Spell=cumsum(!duplicated(x[, 3:6])))
  }), 
  na.omit(d)$Caseid), d, all=TRUE)

d <- merge(d, aggregate(list(avgWage=d$Wage), 
                        list(Caseid=d$Caseid, Spell=d$Spell), 
                        mean, na.rm=TRUE), 
           all.x=TRUE)

d[order(d$Caseid, d$Year), ]
```

Note, though, that this returns `NA` for `Wage` and `avgWage` where rows contain `NA`.

Comment: Actually, I think yours is pretty good.  I like your use of `duplicated`, though does it basically assume the ID vars are always increasing (wondering if someone could go from employer 1, to 2, and then back?  Also, you made me realize I totally forgot average wages.

Comment: Good point about flipping back and forth between states - hadn't thought of that. Still, data.table seems to be the simplest way to go for many of these types of problems - must investigate further :)

Answer (score 4):

Here is a `data.table` solution:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(df)
dt[
  !is.na(Unemployed), 
  change:=
    as.numeric(
      apply(
        vapply(.SD, function(x) as.logical(c(0, diff(x))), logical(.N)),
        1,
        any
    ) ),
  by=Caseid, 
  .SDcols=3:6
]
dt[, spell:=cumsum(ifelse(is.na(change), 0, change)) + 1, by=Caseid]
dt[, avgWage:=mean(Wage, na.rm=T), by=list(Caseid, spell)]
dt
#     Caseid Year Unemployed EmployerID occID indID Wage change spell avgWage
#  1:      1 1999          0          1     1     1    5      0     1       5
#  2:      1 2000         NA         NA    NA    NA   NA     NA     1       5
#  3:      1 2001         NA         NA    NA    NA   NA     NA     1       5
#  4:      1 2002          0          1     1     2    6      1     2       6
#  5:      2 1999          0          1     1     1    4      0     1       5
#  6:      2 2000          0          1     1     1    5      0     1       5
#  7:      2 2001          0          1     1     1    6      0     1       5
#  8:      2 2002          1          1     1     1    6      1     2       6
#  9:      3 1999          0          1     1     1    4      0     1       4
# 10:      3 2000          0          3     1     1    5      1     2       5
# 11:      3 2001          0          1     4     1    5      1     3       5
# 12:      3 2002         NA         NA    NA    NA   NA     NA     3       5
# 13:      4 1999          0          1     1     1    5      0     1       6
# 14:      4 2000          0          1     1     1    5      0     1       6
# 15:      4 2001          0          1     1     1    7      0     1       6
# 16:      4 2002          0          1     1     1    7      0     1       6
```

Data, for debugging:

```
df <- structure(list(Caseid = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), Year = c(1999L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 
1999L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 1999L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 1999L, 
2000L, 2001L, 2002L), Unemployed = c(0L, NA, NA, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, NA, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), EmployerID = c(1L, NA, 
NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), occID = c(1L, 
NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
    indID = c(1L, NA, NA, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Wage = c(5, NA, NA, 6, 4, 5, 6, 6, 4, 5, 
    5, NA, 5, 5, 7, 7)), .Names = c("Caseid", "Year", "Unemployed", 
"EmployerID", "occID", "indID", "Wage"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-16L))
```

---

EDIT: updated to run with new data:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(df)
dt[!is.na(newemp), newemp:=cumsum(newemp), by=caseid]
dt[
  !is.na(unemp), 
  change:=
    as.numeric(
      apply(
        vapply(.SD, function(x) as.logical(c(0, diff(x))), logical(.N)),
        1,
        any
    ) ),
  by=caseid, 
  .SDcols=3:6
]
dt[, spell:=cumsum(ifelse(is.na(change), 0, change)) + 1, by=caseid]
dt[, avgWage:=mean(lwage, na.rm=T), by=list(caseid, spell)]
dt
```

Note the new data has some additional issues that aren't fully dealt with (i.e. some rows are partially NA, instead of fully NA as in the original).  You'll have to tinker with the logic to get it to do exactly what you want.

Comment: When running your code, @BrodieG, I get the following error:   

Error in apply(vapply(.SD, function(x) as.logical(c(0, diff(x))), logical(.N)),  : 
  dim(X) must have a positive length

Comment: @maxmarx, you need to add the line `library(data.table)` at the beginning of your script, and `install.packages("data.table")` if that isn't a currently installed package; edited the answer to show that.

Comment: Got that already @BrodieG.  Thank you for your help by the way.  I'm new to R trying to switch over from Stata.

Comment: No, @BrodieG, sorry for the confusion, I just meant that I loaded the library and and installed the data.table package.  I'm still getting the positive length error.

Comment: @maxmarx, then it might be somehow our data is not the same.  Can you try with the `dput` I just added at the end of the question.  You can just copy that into your console, and then run the code.

Comment: When I run the code with the data you provided it works.  @BrodieG could the error be caused by my data containing different vector types.  For example I noticed your unemployed variable is an _integer_ where as mine is a _double_.

Comment: why don't you `dput` your data at the end of the question and I can see what the problem is on my side.

Comment: I've posted it up above, @BrodieG.  As I note the actual data was a little different then the example.  The newemp variable (new employer) should trigger a new spell when newemp=1.  For example a series of 4 cases where newemp=1 in each year should be four separate spells not 1 spell.  Forgive the sloppiness, again this was my first Q on here.  I'm also having trouble formatting the data like you did, but hopefully that should do.  Again thanks for the help.

Comment: @maxmarx, I think you missed part of the dput.  If you have a lot of rows, then subset to a meaningful amount of rows, and dput that.

Comment: I think there was an extra return at the end of the original this should work now. @BrodieG

Comment: @maxmarx, this still works for me.  I had to change a couple of variable names, but it was fine.  In order to deal with the `unemp` issue you mention, I just ran `dt[!is.na(newemp), newemp:=cumsum(newemp), by=caseid]` to make the variable be what I thought it was.  I would recommend you clear your workspace and start by pasting the `dput`, then running the updated code above (about to add it).  I'm about as far as I can go on this.  Also, restart R as well.

Comment: [@BrodieG], It works with the sub-setted dataset that I presented to you, the issue seems to be when I expand to the full sample.  It starts generating the error if I run the apply on more then 1200 cases at a time.  I'm not sure why, but that is it's limit.  I guess I'll just run it on 1200 case incriminates and then rbind them together.

Comment: @maxmarx, there is almost certainly funny about the data at around the 1200 case that causes the logic to break.  Ideally you would just subset to include that portion.  I don't think size alone is a problem, it almost certainly has to be a new condition that appears that we haven't thought about.

Comment: [@BrodieG] It appears that within caseid when there is a single case in 1979 but no subsequent observations (i.e. NA for all observations through 2010) it doesn't work. As a result it fails to generate a value for change or spell on all subsequent cases.